# Translating 2D image with RGB colours along axes

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create my own voronoi diagram. I have an arbitrary shape defined by their x and y coordinates stored in separate vectors. Inside this shape are some points of interest (with known coordinates) that belong to two different groups and act as seeds to the voronoi diagram. As an example, the whole diagram ranges from x=-10 to x=90 and y=-20 to y=60. The boundary shape is not rectangular but falls within the axes range above.

What I have done so far is to create a 3D matrix (100 X 80 X 3), C, with all ones so that the default colour will be white. I then looped through from i=1:100, j=1:80, testing individual pixels to see if they fall within the shape using inpolygon. If they do, I then find out which point is the pixel closest to and assign it a colour based on whether the closest point belongs to group 1 or 2.

All is good so far. I then used imagesc to display the image with a custom axis range. The problem is that the voronoi diagram has the general shape but it is off in terms of position as the pixel coordinates are different from the actual world coordinates.

I tried to map it using imref2d but I do not know how it really works or how to display the image after using imref2d. Please help me on this.

I am open to other methods too!

Thank you!

Edit:
As requested, let me give a more detailed example and explanation of my problem.

Let us assume a simple diamond shape boundary with the following vectors and 4 points with the following coordinate vectors:

```
%Boundary vectors
Boundary_X = [-5 40 85 40 -5];
Boundary_Y = [20 50 20 -10 20];

%Point vectors
Group_One_X = [20 30];
Group_One_Y = [10 40];
Group_Two_X = [50 70];
Group_Two_Y = [5 20];
```

Next I plot all of them, with different groups having different colours.

```
%Plot boundary and points
hold on
plot(Boundary_X,Boundary_Y)
scatter(Group_One_X,Group_One_Y,10,'MarkerFaceColor','Black',...
'MarkerEdgeColor','Black')
scatter(Group_Two_X,Group_Two_Y,10,'MarkerFaceColor','Red',...
'MarkerEdgeColor','Red')
hold off
axis([-10, 90, -20, 60])
```

This is the result:
[Boundary with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkJRC.jpg)

Next I test the whole graph area pixel by pixel, and colour them either cyan or yellow depending on whether they are closer to group 1 or 2 points.

```
%Create pixel vector with default white colour
C=ones(100,80,3);
Colour_One = [0 1 1];
Colour_Two = [1 1 0];

%Loop through whole diagram
for i=1:100
    for j=1:80
    x=i;
    y=j
        if inpolygon(x,y,Boundary_X,Boundary_Y)
            %Code for testing which point is pixel closest to
            %If closest to group 1, assign group 1 colour, else group 2
            %colour
        end
    end
end

%Display image
hold on
imagesc(C)
hold off
```

This is the result
[Failed Voronoi Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jknrh.jpg)

The shape is somewhat correct for the right side but not for the others. I understand that this because my world coordinates start from negative values but the pixel coordinates start from 1.

Hence I am at a lost as to how can I solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: [Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @flawr Hey I have provided an example as requested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to notice is that you have to [convert between image and plot coordinates](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html). The plot coordinates are `(x,y)` where `x` goes to the right, and `y` goes up. The matrix coordinates are `(i,j)` where `i` goes down, and `j` to the right. An easy way to do this is with the use of `vec_X,vec_Y` as shown below.

Another solution for the newer Matlab versions would be - as you said - using [`imref2d`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d-class.html) but unfortunately I have no experience with that command.

[image: plot]

```
%Boundary vectors
Boundary_X = [-5 40 85 40 -5];
Boundary_Y = [20 50 20 -10 20];

%Point vectors
Group_One_X = [20 30];
Group_One_Y = [10 40];
Group_Two_X = [50 70];
Group_Two_Y = [5 20];

%Coordinate system
min_X = -10;
max_X = 90;
min_Y = -20;
max_Y = 60;
axis([min_X, max_X, min_Y, max_Y])

%Create pixel vector with default white colour
rows_N = 100;
columns_N = 80;
C=ones(rows_N,columns_N,3);

%These vectors say where each of the pixels is in the plot coordinate
%system
vec_X = linspace(min_X,max_X,columns_N);
vec_Y = linspace(min_Y,max_Y,rows_N);
Colour_One = [0 1 1];
Colour_Two = [1 1 0];

%Loop through whole diagram
for i=1:100
    for j=1:80
        if inpolygon(vec_X(j),vec_Y(i),Boundary_X,Boundary_Y)
            %calculate distance to each point
            Distances_One = zeros(size(Group_One_X));
            Distances_Two = zeros(size(Group_Two_X));
            for k=1:numel(Group_One_X);
                Distances_One(k) = norm([Group_One_X(k),Group_One_Y(k)]-[vec_X(j),vec_Y(i)]);%assuming euclidean norm, but can be adjusted to whatever norm you need
            end
            for k=1:numel(Group_Two_X);
                Distances_Two(k) = norm([Group_Two_X(k),Group_Two_Y(k)]-[vec_X(j),vec_Y(i)]);%assuming euclidean norm, but can be adjusted to whatever norm you need
            end
            if min(Distances_One) < min(Distances_Two);
                C(i,j,:) = Colour_One; 
            else
                C(i,j,:) = Colour_Two;
            end  
        end
    end
end

%Display image

imagesc(vec_X,vec_Y,C) %lets you draw the image according to vec_X and vec_Y
%Plot boundary and points
hold on
plot(Boundary_X,Boundary_Y)
scatter(Group_One_X,Group_One_Y,10,'MarkerFaceColor','Black',...
'MarkerEdgeColor','Black')
scatter(Group_Two_X,Group_Two_Y,10,'MarkerFaceColor','Red',...
'MarkerEdgeColor','Red')

hold off
```

Comment: Thanks man! This helped me solve my problem. The way you solve it is simpler and easier to follow as opposed to using imref2d. Cheers!